# sum 'distinct' rows with same values

Tags: sql

I have a database which has a feeder that may have several distributors, each which may have several transformers, each which may have several clients and a certain kVA (power that gets to the clients).
And I have the following code:

```
SELECT f.feeder,
    d.distributor,
    count(DISTINCT t.transformer) AS total_transformers,
    sum(t.Kvan) AS Total_KVA,
    count(c.client) AS Clients,
FROM feeders f
    LEFT JOIN distributors d
        ON (d.feeder = f.feeder)
    LEFT JOIN transformers t
        ON (t.transformer = d.transformer)
    LEFT JOIN clients c
        ON (c.transformer = t.transformer)
WHERE d.transformer IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY f.feeder,
    d.distributor,
    f.feeder
ORDER BY f.feeder,
    d.distributor
```

The sum is supposed to bring the sum of the different kVA the transformers have. Each transformer has a certain kVA. Problem is, 1 transformer has 1kVA for all the clients it has connected, but it will sum it as if it was 1kVA per client.
I need to group it on the feeder and distributor (I want to see how much kVA the distributor has and how many clients total).
So what should be "feeder1|dist1|2|600|374" brings me "feeder1|dist1|2|130000|374" (1 transformer has 200 kVA and the otherone 400, but it will sum these two 374 times instead of 400+200)

Comment: Format the question, tag RDBMS involved and add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Your `Where` clause just turned your `Left Join` into an `Inner Join`. And not that it matters, you don't need to group by `feeder` twice.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Your data model seems a little messy, in that you've specified a distributor can have many transformers (and logic suggests that a transformer is only on a single distributor) yet your query implies that the transformer ID is on the distributor record, which normally implies the opposite relationship ...

So if that's right, it must mean that you have multiple records in the distributors table for the same distributor - i.e. distributor can't then be a unique key in distributors table, which makes the query quite hard to reason accurately about.  (e.g. What happens if the records for a distributor don't all have the same feeder ID on them?  I'm guessing you wouldn't like the answer so much...  Presumably you mean for that to be impossible, but if the model is as described it's not impossible.  And worse I'm now second-guessing whether the apparent keys on the other tables are in fact unique... But I digress...)

Or maybe something else is broken.  Point is the info you've given may be inconsistent or incomplete.  Since I'm inferring an abnormal data model I can't guarantee the following is bug-free (though if you provide more detail so I can make fewer guesses, I may be able to refine the answer)...

So you know the trouble is that by the time you're ready to do the aggregation, the transformer data is embedded in a larger row that isn't based just on the identity of the transformer.  There are a couple ways you could fix it, basically all centered on changing how you look at the aggregation of values.  Here's one option:

```
select f.feeder
     , dtc.distributor
       -- next values work because transformer is already unique per group
     , count(dtc.transformer) total_transformers
     , sum(dtc.kvam) total_kvam
     , sum(dtc.clients) clients
  from      feeder f
       join (select d.distributor
                  , d.feeder
                  , t.transformer
                  , max(t.kvan) as kvan   -- or min, doesn't matter
                  , count(distinct c.client) clients
               from           distributors d
                    left join transformers t
                           on d.transformer = t.transformer
                    left join clients c
                           on c.transformer = t.transformer
              where d.transformer is not null
              group by d.distributor, d.feeder, t.transformer
            ) dtc
         on dtc.feeder = f.feeder
 group by f.feeder, dtc.distributor
```

A few notes:

I changed the outer query join to an inner join, because any null rows from the original left join from `feeder` would be eliminated by the original where clause.

I kept the where clause anyway; having it along side the `distributor`-to-`transformer` left join is a little weird but is different from either an inner join or an outer join without the where clause (since the where clause acts on the left table's value).  I'm avoiding changing the semantics from your original query, but it's weird enough this is something you might want to take another look at.

What using the subquery does here is, the inner query returns one row per feeder/distributor/transformer - i.e. for each feeder/distributor it returns one row per transformer.  That row is itself an aggregate so that we can count clients, but since all rows in that aggregation come from the same transformer record we can use `max()` to get that single record's `kvan` value onto the aggregation.